# Which classification method to choose?

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference, logistic-regression

I am working on a statistics project in which I analyze 4 different classification methods (mostly for binary classification and with quantitative input variables).

On the one hand I'm studying logistic regression with a lineal model or in combination with generalized additive models (piecewise polynomial, p-splines, natural splines...).

On the other hand, I also deal with de kNN algorithm (k-nearest neighbor) and the SVM.

I would like to include a section in my project where I explain which method to choose but I do not know how to approach that based on the different natures of the data.

Any help/hint?

Comment: The optimal classification method (and parameters) depends upon the problem at hand.  From the "No Free Lunch" theorems, we know that there is no universally "best" classifier.

Comment: That's right, but once you have some data to classify which are the general criteria by which you prefer some methods over others? There is some kind of preference?

Comment: Depends on *WHAT* data you've collected... not that you *HAVE* collected data!

Comment: I think I didn't explain it well. I mean for example, if you have data that is not separable by hyperplanes, maybe in that case you prefer to use kNN rather than SVM. I mean those kinds of criteria, if they exist.